# Implement counter with digits and letters in php

Tags: php

I've a database field that it can store only 5 digits/chars.
It is used as a counter for electronic invoice (in Italy).

Every time i'll send an invoice to a client, i need to increment the counter.

So, if I use only digits, I can increment it to max 99999.

I'd like to use letters and digits to increment the range.
From 00000 to ZZZZZ. (important is using 5 chars, so 00000 is correct. 0 is incorrect. So I use `str_pad`)

So, for example when i get 00009, the next it needs to be 0000A (and not 00010 like expected in normal count)

When i get 0000Z, then next has to be 00010.

What's the best way to do it with a function using php?

```
function increment_counter() {

   //read actual counter from DB
   $counter = get_actual_counter_from_db();

   //$counter++; //this works if I use only digits... but for digits/letters?

   $counter = str_pad($counter, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

   //update DB with new counter

   update_counter_in_db($counter);

}
```

Comment: You could also look at [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) and [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

Comment: @Giuseppe, Personally I would simply create a converter to convert from your number to a serial string, and likewise back. I've created a simple script that will do (mostly) what you're looking for [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/S67QS3zYzdu3lFtx). If they provide a serial number, just convert it to an integer and search the db for that int. If you want to output it for formatting, use toString() method.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only caveat to my above code, was I couldn't figure out how to allow for '00010'. When I add 0 to the keyspace, is screws up the algorithm because '01' is not the same as '1' (Having a zero would actually fill in the keyspace, and I'm not too sure how to go about that).